# Can one add values to a C enum once it has been created?

Tags: c, enums

I tried a Google search for it but didn't come up with anything. Does anyone know if this can be done? If not is there an elegant work around this?

Update: I think Frank Osterfeld's answer is the most clear solution. Thanks for all the other answers, I've upvoted your answers.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `enum` are a compile-time thing. At runtime, only integral values exist. What does "create an enum" means to you? When does it happen, for you?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? A little context will help. Bascially enums are a collection of things - playing cards, months of the year, day of the week etc.. You cannot add an extra day to the week - despite a manager think that they can!

Comment: @Ed: ok, then I'll need you to come in on Saturday

Comment: MY last manager did not like my response or me showing him my contract. The second word of that conversation was *off* - My child is more important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others said, you cannot redeclare an enum (in which context, which one should be used anyway?).

If you just need some constants, and want extend them for a special case, you can use multiple enum declarations, one extending the other and then use ints to hold the values:

```
enum Error { NoError=0, AllIsBroken, WhatTheHellAreYouDoing, UserDefinedError };

enum NetworkError { HostNotFound=UserDefinedError+1, ConnectionTimeout, ... };

int error = HostNotFound;

if ( error == NoError )
    ...
if ( error == HostNotFound )
    ...
```

Comment: I think this is the most clear solution. Thanks for all the other answers, I've upvoted your answers.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot reopen the same enum with different value:

```
enum Colors { Red, Blue, Yellow };
enum Colors { Green = 3 }; // ERROR
```

In C, however, all enums are automatically convertable to each other. So just create a new enum, like this:

```
enum Colors { Red, Blue, Yellow };
enum MoreColors { Green = 3 };

int foo()
{
  enum Colors c;
  c = Green; // This will compile
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No; once an enumeration type is complete, you can't extend it:

```
enum Blarney { Kirkpatrick, Donegal, Ireland };

enum Blarney { Eire = 3 };  // Not allowed!
```

There isn't a workaround for it, at one level.  At another level, you can simply use `int` values to hold items from an enumeration:

```
enum Blarney { Kirkpatrick, Donegal, Ireland };
enum BlarneyX { Eire = 3 };

void function(void)
{
    enum Blarney b = Kirkpatrick;
    int y = Kirkpatrick;

    y = Eire;
    y = Donegal;
    switch (y)
    {
    case Kirkpatrick:
    case Donegal:
         printf("Something\n");
         break;
    case Eire:
         printf("Different\n");
         break;
    }

    switch (b)
    {
    case Kirkpatrick:
         printf("Kirkpatrick\n");
         break;
    case Donegal:
         printf("Donegal\n");
         break;
     }
     ...
}
```

The compiler might warn you about missing out the case `Ireland` in the second `switch`; it can't do so with the first.

Answer (score 2):

No.  As others have said, a C enum is a compile-time thing.

In some languages, like Javascript, you can create objects that are treated as enums.  For example:

```
var Colors = { "Red":0xf00, "Blue":0x00f, "Green":0x0f0 };
Colors["Cyan"]=0x0ff;

var bgColor = Colors.Red;
```

If you need to simulate this method of mapping strings to values in C (not C++), you'll need some sort of tree or hash table which is not part of the C standard library.  In C++, just use `std::map<std::string, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "once it has been created"? enums are *types*, that are "created" at compile time. 
But since all enums share the same "namespace" (a concept that does not exists in C), you can declare other enums independently. However, you can't "redeclare" an enum.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add to an 'enum', because the values could be replaced with constants when the translation unit that uses those values is compiled, depending on debugging options, optimization, etc. Besides, what would possibly reference the new values in the already compiled translation unit? You'd have to recompile.